# Should I stop replication logreader and distribution jobs during database maintenance (reindexing, updating stats, and checkdb)?

Tags: sql-server, reindex, transactional-replication, dbcc

I have transactional replication setup in SQL Server 2022. I have a distribution server running push subscriptions to subscribers. I'm trying to figure out if I need to stop replication jobs (log reader and distribution jobs) when running maintenance jobs such as backups, re-indexing, update stats, and DBCC maintenance? I'm trying to avoid causing any replication outage due to maintenance jobs.

Replication jobs are setup to run continuously when SQL Server starts. I did this for best practices because we were seeing latency when I scheduled these jobs instead of running them continuously. I made reset jobs to run continuously among a few other changes and we no longer see latency.

If I need to stop jobs while running maintenance jobs; can someone recommend the best way to do this.  Like I said, I was trying to avoid scheduling these jobs.  I was thinking if needed; I could put a step in the first maintenance job that is scheduled to run to stop replication job and restart it after the last step of the last maintenance job. Any thoughts?

I haven't tried to run maintenance jobs yet as this is in a new production environment, and I didn't want to have to apply another snapshot in case maintenance jobs break replication.